# How to get Suggestion for a gesture in android?

Tags: android, gesture

Hello there I need to create a screen for digital signature. I need to have some suggestions after creating a sign. How can I achieve this functionality? Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean like a showcase viewer?

Comment: Screenshots? Wireframe? Code samples?

Comment: Haven't got anything its just an idea.. dont know how to implement ..thats why i'm asking here

Comment: Do you want to do the signature capture ?

Comment: Yes @AshishRawat but I want it to provide some suggestions too (because user may not create gesture properly)

Comment: What do u mean by suggestion ? Please give example

Comment: such as user writes the letter 's' but it is not that recognisable so I want to provide user some suggestion whether he wanted to write 's' or 'x' or 'c'.

Comment: I can only help you regarding signature capture, suggestion you have to figure out